# VMWare Ubuntu warns me on no disk space, but GParted shows there is lots of space

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, diskspace, vmware-player

I have a vmware ubuntu allocated with 300G of disk space, but recently I got a disk space warning.

I run `df -h` as this:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    797M   88M  710M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/vgroot-root   25G   18G  5.8G  76% /
tmpfs                    3.9G  106M  3.8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                945M   75M  806M   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vgroot-home   15G   14G   56K 100% /home
vmhgfs-fuse              239G  200G   40G  84% /mnt/hgfs
tmpfs                    797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/999
tmpfs                    797M   64K  797M   1% /run/user/500
```

yes I see /home directory is 100% full, but know can I enlarge it?

I tried to run `gparted`, but there seems to be a lot of space.

[image: gparted]

Comment: Someone please DELETE this question because I have asked it in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134934/how-to-increase-the-size-of-home-in-a-vmware-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

What works for me was lowering space for Previous versions of files (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7).

1.Click Start Icon
2.Left Click on "Computer" and click on Properties
3.Click on "System Protection" on left side
4.Click on Disk and "Configure"
5.Lower your quota

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm asking for Ubuntu issues, not Windows

Answer (score 0):

As a quick & easy fix is try a different data (SATA?) cable, maybe even power cable.

Check the syslog (usually /var/log/syslog & dmesg for any messages about the drive when it disappears/reappears.
You might even be able to hear the drive working while testing / reading / writing, or even just spinning idle. So if it suddenly goes quiet while it should be working that's bad, especially if it disappears from all Linux tools / listings.

That's a little weird that the self test didn't log anything...

You could try running the short self-test again, optionally in -C, --captive mode (some of my older drives would always abort the test ~90% if captive).
While testing (not in captive mode) you could check the test's status with smartctl -c /dev/sdX to see "Self-test execution status:" and the next line has % remaining. Or just cut out those lines with:
smartctl -c /dev/sdX | grep "^Self" -A1

-c will also show what tests are supported.

Try the other self tests (conveyance, offline, long)

I like smartctl --xall to see all the results.

I believe the "SMART Attributes Data Structure -> Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds" has "problem" attributes showing a "VALUE" of 100 or less (higher numbers being better)
the "RAW_VALUES" are very vendor specific & might be a code & might not have any direct relation to the attribute (Power_On_Minutes & Power_Cycle_Count should be actual minutes & a count, but there may be no guarantees)
Drives can put themselves to sleep after a while, but they should still remain connected & listed in Linux. There's a smartctl command to get & set it, here's the relevant section from the man page: